# I don't know how to stop making it show up as the two things separated by a comma and in parentheses

Tags: python, python-3.x

in this line of code

```
 a = (True)
note = (input("enter notes here:"))
copy = note
while a == True:
    edita = (input("if you want to add or edit anything write, edit if you are done using notes say no (edit, or no)."))
    if edita == "edit":
        note_2 = eval(input(note))
        note = copy,note_2
        copy = note
```

it prints as (copy, note_2) but I want it to print as copynote_2 not separated at all how do
I fix it.

I have tried many ways to fix I just can't figure it out, I am really new to coding so I don't know much so it would help if you explained your answer to me and made it simple.

Comment: are `copy` and `note_2` strings? If so you can do `note = copy + note_2` to concatenate them together.

Comment: Please make this a small running script to show the problem. We don't know what is in those two variables or what you mean by the expected result. Surely not the variable names themselves. Maybe its as simple as `note = "".join((copy, note_2))`.

Comment: `,` is for creating tuples in Python.

Answer (score 0):

`note = copy + note_2`

In this code, the + operator will combine the contents of the copy and note_2 strings together, creating a single string without any separation, considering your copy and note_2 variables are holding data of string type.